# Getting the runtime of a delayed job in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, runtime, delayed-job

I've got a delayed job running and I want to saved the runtime when it finishes, the worker logs the runtime to the logs like this...

```
XXXXXJob completed after 1.6372
```

I was wondering how you access this statistic from inside the delayed job class?

I've tried `self.runtime` but that's throwing an error.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `delayed_job` gem doesn't provide API for accessing that stats. Looks like [here](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/job.rb#L96) is the place were they calculate running time and that's what is happening there:

```
runtime = Benchmark.realtime do
  invoke_job
  destroy
end
logger.info "* [JOB] #{name} completed after %.4f" % runtime
```

So `runtime` is calculated using [`Benchmark`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) module and logged, but it's not stored anywhere for later usage.

Though, you still can calculate runtime of the job yourself by wrapping its logic with similar [`Benchmark.realtime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-realtime) call or something like that.

Comment: Another option would be opening up the class and changing the behavior by overriding the run method.

Comment: Yes, reopening the class can solve most of the problems like that in ruby. But it's the utmost solution and I'd better avoid it if possible. Even if you need timing for every background job in your app you can create your own `BaseJob` class, implement required logic and derive all your jobs from this class.

Comment: Wrapping the job in a Benchmark worked perfectly, the time logged by dj matched the Benchmark result. If it needs to be reused more I'll create it's own base job, but it's ok as a one-off.